# Some controls are not drawing, seemingly at random

Tags: mfc

I'm trying to write a little MFC app just for myself, to test some AI's I'm training.

So I added a picture control and a static control where I can paint stuff freely in the OnPaint() method of my main Window.

It seems to work when just drawing my app once, but I now added a loop that performs OnPaint() multiple times before stopping.

When in this loop, some other controls don't show up, for example all my buttons are gone, and some sliders even are missing some times, but other times, they're there.

My code goes like this:

```cpp
void CKiUebung1Dlg::OnBnClickedButtongo()
{
    m_bisGoing = true;
    OnPaint();
    if(m_fDiagramData.size() <= 0)
    {
        m_fDiagramData.push_back((float)rand() / RAND_MAX);
        InvalidateRect(NULL, TRUE);
    }
    OnPaint();
    for(int i(9); i >= 0; --i)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        m_fDiagramData.push_back((float)rand() / RAND_MAX);
        InvalidateRect(NULL, TRUE);
        OnPaint();
    }
    m_bisGoing = false;
    OnPaint();
}
```

```cpp
void CKiUebung1Dlg::OnPaint()
{
    if(IsIconic())
    {
        CPaintDC dc(this); // Gerätekontext zum Zeichnen

        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, reinterpret_cast<WPARAM>(dc.GetSafeHdc()), 0);

        // Symbol in Clientrechteck zentrieren
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Symbol zeichnen
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else
    {
        CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    }
    {
        constexpr const int border = 5;
        CPaintDC dc(&m_cDiagram);
        CRect l_cPos;
        m_cDiagram.GetClientRect(&l_cPos);
        const int width(l_cPos.Width() - border * 2 - 2), height(l_cPos.Height() - border * 2 - 12);
        const int numPoints(m_fDiagramData.size());
        POINT* points(new POINT[numPoints]);
        for(int i(numPoints - 1); i >= 0; --i)
        {
            const int
                x((float)i / (numPoints - 1) * width + border + 1),
                y(height - m_fDiagramData[i] * height + border + 9);
            points[i] = { x,y };
        }
        dc.Polyline(points, numPoints);

        static CString going(_T(" "));
        if(m_bisGoing) { going += _T("."); if(going.GetLength() > 300) going = _T(" ."); }
        else going = _T(" ");
        float fprog(0); if(m_fDiagramData.size() > 0) fprog = m_fDiagramData.back();
        CString prog; prog.Format(_T("Progress %03.2f%%"), fprog * 100); if(m_bisGoing) prog += going;
        m_cDiagram.SetWindowTextW(prog);

        m_cDiagram.RedrawWindow();

        delete[] points;
    }
}
```

This is how it looks when the loop isn't running:

[image: This is how it looks when the loop isn't running]

This is how it looks when the loop is running:

[image: This is how it looks when the loop is running]

Comment: *"a loop that performs OnPaint() multiple times"* - That sounds odd. `OnPaint` is usually a message handler, not a regular function you should call. And while you are in your message handler, all message processing stops, i.e. no `WM_PAINT` handlers for your controls run. You can limit the damage by setting the `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` style on your control parent, but you really need to solve the core issue. Hard to provide a solution without seeing a [mcve].

Comment: I added some code that fakes the actions behind the app. What can i replace OnPaint() with, if i'm not supposed to call that directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have trouble understanding how invalidating/painting works.
The documentation you should read first is:
**[Painting and Drawing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162759(v=vs.85).aspx)**

While many developers recommend painting only in `WM_PAINT` processing (`OnPaint()` in MFC), this is not always the best solution, because this message is low-priority, painting may not be immediate (have a "choppy" feel), and you may get a "flickering" effect.

Instead, I sometimes recommend a mix of drawing and painting:

- Employ painting in `WM_PAINT` processing. This should paint the whole client area (or only the invalidated part of it, if you want a more "optimized" implementation). Please note that `WM_PAINT` message may be received as a result of invalidating a part or all of the client area, due to moving, resizing, unhiding etc the window, in addition to programmatically invalidating it. So in response to a `WM_PAINT` message you should perform a full repaint, ie all the items you want to be displayed.
- Employ drawing for the changes you want to be shown immediately, while the application is busy (not waiting for the "asynchronous" `WM_PAINT` message to be received). Please note that these should be in `WM_PAINT` processing as well, so you rather have to write some drawing/painting routines, taking a `HDC` (or `CDC*`) as a parameter (along any other parameter needed), and call them from both the `OnPaint()` function (passing the `ClientDC` there) and from your additional drawing actions needed (passing a `CDC*` acquired by calling `GetDC()`).

So, let me share my experience with an application I wrote some (long) time ago. It's an image-display/manipulation (among others) application, processing images in a custom format, and using a special library, which was rather "slow", as it only provided a function to display the image in the device context (this includes possible cropping, adjustments, resizing etc which are CPU-costly operations). Here is an image:

[image]

You can see the user performing a selection. The application has to display the image, and possibly the selection rectangle on top of it, and of course that's what `OnPaint()` does. An "easy" (albeit technically "correct") implementation would be to call `Invalidate()` or `InvalidateRect()` in response each mouse move message (while selecting). This would cause a full repaint (which is "OK"), but also suffer from performance problems, due to the slow image-library: if you also call `UpdateWindow()` after invalidating (requesting an immediate refresh) performance would be sluggish (having to reprocess/redisplay the image), if not, the refresh would just take place some (noticeable) time later. This was solved by employing drawign (not painting) in response to the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message: no invalidating there, instead drawing just the selection rectangle (after restoring the part modified by the previous selection message - I only backup/restore the four sides of the frame, not the whole rectangle). As a result, the application is responsive and the operation smooth, despite the slow library, and shows the image and the selection correctly, even if you switch to another application and then back to it, while the selection is being tracked (dashed line).

Some notes and suggestion about your implementation (it has quite a few issues):

- As other members have noted, you may not call `OnPaint()` yourself. Especially those calls after `Invalidate()` make absolutely no sense. Instead, call `UpdateWindow()`, if you want an immediate update.
- Imo it is NOT OK to perform calculations within `OnPaint()`, and I mean those points calculations (although in your case the calculation is rather trivial). `OnPaint()` should just display the data calculated in another part of your code.
- Also, setting the `m_cDiagram` text and repainting from within `OnPaint()` is not OK either (may cause additional paint requests). Better move these into `OnBnClickedButtongo()`.
- You don't need to invalidate (and particularly erase) the whole client area to cause some controls to be repainted, instead invalidate only those controls. Remember, the `sleep_for()` function is blocking, and the `WM_PAINT` message won't be sent and processed while your loop is running.
- Btw, consider a non-blocking approach, eg using a timer, as @Barmak Shemirani suggested. Alternatively, it may be possible to write a "non-blocing `sleep()`" by running the message-loop yourself (take parts of the code in `CWinApp::Run()` and modify it).
- Since you have a dialog and created separate controls to display your data, using `OnPaint()` is not a good implementation, as it affects (paints) the whole client area. It is mostly useful for classes like `CView` or `CScrollView` (or custom-painting `CWnd`s in general). You paint the graph on the dialog's surface, and have to perform calculations to get the coordinates in `m_cDiagram` (btw you can use `GetWindowRect()` and then `ScreenToClient()` instead) but it would be best to use an owner-drawn control (to paint/draw the graph on), and it's not really difficult, you just have to respond to paint requests (just as in `OnPaint()`), and the device context you get can paint on the control only, not on the dialog; coordinates are relative to the control's client area, starting from (0,0).

Hope this helps

Comment: If you call `Invalidate()` from a `WM_MOUSEMOVE` handler, no `WM_PAINT` is generated (mouse input has higher priority than paint messages). The 'correct' way to render a focus rectangle is to call [DrawFocusRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawfocusrect). It has a particularly interesting feature: While it performs a destructive operation, the initial image can be restored by performing the same operation again. That allows you to draw a focus rectangle **without** running a full re-paint of the image.

Comment: Very practical answer. I will use this to correct my program. Only the part about a non-blocking timer is not applicable, as this is the part that simulates my calculations in the background for MCVE reasons, which obviously has to be blocking. Sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: @IInspectable, thanks for commenting. `WM_PAINT` messages can indeed be sent and processed between `WM_MOUSEMOVE` ones, if the user does not move the mouse too fast. Although updates will be erratic, the method is "correct" in that it will finally paint the image correctly, ie it's a "quick" and yes, clumsy, but not "dirty" implementation.
As for drawing the rectangle, indeed, I had tried inverting at first (although I was calling `BitBlt()` with `DSTINVERT` rop parameter rather than `DrawFocusRect()`), (cont)

Comment: (cont) but the results were not good, for such grayscale images, because the inverse is most of the time another grayscale value, quite close to the original, and the selection rectangle's shades differ. Varied between almost invisible and ugly. My method isn't really more complicated than using `DrawFocusRect()` because this too requires restoring the previous rectangle before drawing the new one - of course I have to backup the frame before drawing it, but this is only done at a single point (just before drawing) so there's no extra complexity.

Comment: Restoring an image after `DrawFocusRect` requires that you keep track of a single `RECT` structure (that's 16 bytes). And it involves paining only those pixels that changed. This is quite (noticeably) different from blitting tens and hundreds of kilobytes on every mouse move.

Comment: Not really, I'm blitting the frame only, that is the four sides of the rectangle (it's four calls to `BitBlt()`), not the interior - no need to backup/restore a part of the image that doesn't change. It's really fast. Indeed, I need to also maintain the backup bitmaps (in addition to the rectangle you mentioned) but that's all.

Comment: You're also (in *addition*) going to need to keep track of the previous selection rectangle. Otherwise you won't be able to restore the dirty region. If you forget that, you'll see visual artifacts in case a user decides to *shrink* the selection rectangle.

Answer (score 3):

[`CWnd::OnPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#onpaint) is a response to [`WM_PAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/wm-paint) message and should not be called directly.

`WM_PAINT` calls `CWnd::OnPaint`, which calls [`CPaintDC dc(this)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cpaintdc-class#cpaintdc), which in turns calls [`BeginPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-beginpaint)/[`EndPaint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-endpaint) APIs. This sequence of message+response should be left as is.

Therefore `CPaintDC dc(this)` must appear once - and only once - inside `OnPaint`, and not anywhere else. Override `OnPaint` as follows:

```cpp
void CMyDialog::OnPaint()
{
    CDialogEx::OnPaint(); //this will call CPaintDC dc(this);

    //optional: 
    CClientDC dc(this); //CClientDC can be used anywhere in a valid window
    //use dc for drawing
}

//or
void CMyDialog::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); 
    //use dc for drawing
}
```

You also don't need the outdated `if (IsIconic()) {...}` condition.

To force the window to repaint itself, call [`Invalidate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#invalidate) (same thing as [`InvalidateRect(NULL, TRUE)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#invalidaterect))

`InvalidateRect(NULL, TRUE)` is a request to repaint the window. The system will look at this request, and will send `WM_PAINT` message to that window when there is a chance. Therefore a call to `InvalidateRect` may not process the way you expect it to work in a sequential program. For example, a second consecutive call to `InvalidateRect` will not have any effect. Window was already marked to be updated.

> ```cpp
>  for(int i(9); i >= 0; --i)
>  {
>     std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
>     m_fDiagramData.push_back((float)rand() / RAND_MAX);
>     InvalidateRect(NULL, TRUE);
>     OnPaint();
>  }
> ```

`OnPaint()` should be removed from above code. Still, animation is not possible in a single thread (at least not in this manner). The program is busy going through the loop, it cannot deal with `WM_PAINT` and other messages.

So you need an additional thread, or simply use `SetTimer`, and respond to `ON_WM_TIMER()`/`OnTimer` for animation. Example:

```cpp
int counter = 0;

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDialog, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_TIMER()
    ...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMyDialog::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this);
    CString s;
    s.Format(L"%02d", counter);
    dc.TextOut(0, 0, s);
}

void CMyDialog::animate()
{
    counter = 0;
    SetTimer(1, 1000, NULL);
}

void CMyDialog::OnTimer(UINT_PTR n)
{
    if(n == 1)
    {
        Invalidate(); //force repaint
        counter++;
        if(counter == 10)
            KillTimer(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you provided a single-threaded approach to animation, you may want to revisit the paragraph that claims, that this were impossible. The call to `Invalidate()` also doesn't *"force"* a repaint. This is a request. The section on how invalidating part or all of a window were to generate a `WM_PAINT` message is presented in a too simplistic way. `WM_PAINT` messages are generated on demand, when there are no higher-priority messages queued up. A corollary of this is, that multiple calls to `Invalidate()` can be coalesced into a single `WM_PAINT` message.

Comment: @IInspectable, okay I changed the wording.

Comment: [How do I call SetTimer with a timer ID that is guaranteed not to conflict with any other timer ID?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150924-00/?p=91521) As long as you control the window, that's easy: Add an instance member (e.g. `int m_AnimationTimerId;`) and use its address as the timer ID. I never considered the fact, that the ID is pointer-sized, until September 2015.

Comment: @IInspectable Good idea. This only works, of course, if everyone agrees to create timer IDs in this way. @Barmak One should file a request to remove `if (IsIconic()) {...}` from the code the MFC application wizard generates. Code became obsolete with Win95 already.